# Fact Generator (Not Random)

Tags: javascript, function, random

I'm adding a random fact generator to my company's about page. It currently looks like this:

```js
var targetemployee = document.getElementById('targetemployee');
    var factsemployee = [

      'Fact1',
      'Fact2',
      'Fact3',
      'Fact4',
      'Fact5',
    ];
    function newEmployeeFact () {
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * factsemployee.length) | 0;
      targetemployee.innerText = factsemployee[i]

    }
    
    newEmployeeFact();
```

```html
    <div style="text-align: center;">

    <p class="funfact" id="targetemployee"></p><button type="button" class="hover-shadow" style="text-align: middle; font-size: 0.8em; bottom: 0px" onclick="newEmployeeFact()"> NEW FACT </button>

    </div>
```

My problem is that after clicking it a few times, it will sometimes show the same fact instead of a new one so I just want to change is so that it's sequential. Any tips? I'm a JS beginner so I appreciate y'all's help!

Comment: If the selection shall be random it can happen that there will be twice the same fact. Just get the random fact from a list where the last fact has been removed.

Comment: @MEE What does a different source of "randomness" change?

Comment: @Andreas Nothing, but I thougt it may be worth noting that JS (or any other programming language) is just using 'fake' randoms. I have edited my comment.

Comment: Have you tried shuffling the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
var targetemployee = document.getElementById('targetemployee');

var factsOrig = [
    'Fact1',
    'Fact2',
    'Fact3',
    'Fact4',
    'Fact5',
  ];

var factsemployee = factsOrig.slice(0);

function newEmployeeFact () {
    if (!factsemployee.length) {
        factsemployee = factsOrig.slice(0); // Refill array
    }
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * factsemployee.length) | 0;
    targetemployee.innerText = factsemployee[i]
    factsemployee.splice(i, 1); // Remove from active array
}

newEmployeeFact();
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">

<p class="funfact" id="targetemployee"></p><button type="button" class="hover-shadow" style="text-align: middle; font-size: 0.8em; bottom: 0px" onclick="newEmployeeFact()"> NEW FACT </button>

</div>
```